# favorite Recycler view updates only on relaunching app

Tags: java, android

I developed a word app that contains English vocabularies and users can add their favorite word by clicking on a floating button. Every time my favorite list has at list one item it is updated but when it's empty it doesn't show anything but when I run app again list updates. 
if you need any code let me know to send it .

UPDATE:
Inner page :

```
    selectDb();

    if(selectFavoriteState()){
        favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_like);
    }else {
        favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_maylike);
    }

    favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (selectFavoriteState()){
                favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_maylike);
                updateUnfavorited();

            }else {
                favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_like);
                updateFavorited();

            }



        }
    });

 private void selectDb(){
    destpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ielts/";
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(destpath + "/md_book.db", null);
}

private boolean selectFavoriteState(){
    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main WHERE id = " + id, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        favoriteState = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fav"));

    }
    return favoriteState.equals("1");
}

private void updateFavorited(){
    database.execSQL( "UPDATE main SET fav = 1 WHERE id = " + id);

}

private void updateUnfavorited(){
    database.execSQL( "UPDATE main SET fav = 0 WHERE id = " + id);


}
```

**Update 2:**

```
package farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.mainPage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.R;

public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

private int mPage;
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
RecyclerView recyclerView;
AdapterFav adapterFav;


public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);

    if (mPage == 1) {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        AdapterList adapter = new AdapterList(MainActivity.context);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.context));
    }

    if (mPage == 2) {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        adapterFav = new AdapterFav(MainActivity.context);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterFav);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.context));
    }

        return view;

    }


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adapterFav != null){
        adapterFav.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

**Update 3 :AdapterFav**

```
package farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.mainPage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.R;
import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.innerpage.ActivityInnerPage;

public class AdapterFav extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView title;
ImageView avatar;
LinearLayout cardAdapter;

public AdapterFav(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_card_view, parent, false);

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title1);
    avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    cardAdapter = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.card_adapter);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(MainActivity.favorite.get(position).getWord());
    String img = MainActivity.favorite.get(position).getImg();
    int id = MainActivity.context.getResources().getIdentifier(img, "drawable", MainActivity.context.getPackageName());
    holder.avatar.setImageResource(id);
    holder.cardAdapter.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    holder.cardAdapter.setId(position);


}


View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = view.getId();
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.context, ActivityInnerPage.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", "favorite");
        intent.putExtra("id", position + "");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        MainActivity.context.startActivity(intent);


    }
};

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainActivity.favorite.size();
}
}
```

**Update 4: MainActivity**

```
package farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.mainPage;


import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.nabinbhandari.android.permissions.PermissionHandler;
import com.nabinbhandari.android.permissions.Permissions;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.R;
import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.search.ActivitySearch;
import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.setting.ActivitySetting;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static Context context;
public static ArrayList<Structure> list = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Structure> favorite = new ArrayList<>();
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
ImageView hamburger;
SQLiteDatabase database;
String destPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_activity_main);


    Permissions.check(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            " storage permissions are required to copy database", new Permissions.Options()
                    .setSettingsDialogTitle("Warning!").setRationaleDialogTitle("Info"),
            new PermissionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onGranted() {
                    setupDB();
                    selectList();
                    selectFavorite();
                }
            });

    context = getApplicationContext();
    setTabOption();

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    hamburger = findViewById(R.id.hamburger);
    hamburger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
    });

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.exit) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);

                alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.exit);

                alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.exit_ask);
                alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int
                                    which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int
                                    which) {

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.show();
            }else if (id == R.id.search) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySearch.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            } else if (id == R.id.setting) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySetting.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

            }

            return true;
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.exit);

        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.exit_ask);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}


private void setTabOption() {
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            context));
    TabLayout tabStrip = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabStrip.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!list.isEmpty()){
        list.clear();
        selectList();
    } if (!favorite.isEmpty()){
        favorite.clear();
        selectFavorite();
    }
}

private void setupDB() {
    try {
        destPath =
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ielts/";
        File file = new File(destPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("md_book.db"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/md_book.db"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}

private void selectFavorite() {

    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(destPath + "/md_book.db",
            null);
    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main WHERE fav = 1",
            null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"));
        String definition =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("definition"));
        String trans = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("trans"));
        String img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("img"));
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

        Structure struct = new Structure(word, definition, trans, img, id);
        struct.setWord(word);
        struct.setDefinition(definition);
        struct.setTrans(trans);
        struct.setImg(img);
        struct.setId(id);
        favorite.add(struct);

    }

}

private void selectList() {

    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(destPath + "/md_book.db",
            null);
    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"));
        String definition =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("definition"));
        String trans = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("trans"));
        String img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("img"));
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

        Structure struct = new Structure(word, definition, trans, img, id);
        struct.setWord(word);
        struct.setDefinition(definition);
        struct.setTrans(trans);
        struct.setImg(img);
        struct.setId(id);
        list.add(struct);
    }

}

}
```

Update 5 innerpage activity

```
package farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.innerpage;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.R;
    import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.mainPage.AdapterFav;


public class ActivityInnerPage extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView contentDescriptione;
private TextView moreDescriptione;
private ImageView avatar;
private ImageView imgCopy;
private ImageView imgShare;
private ImageView imgSms;
private ImageView imgGmail;
private FloatingActionButton favorite;
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
public String word;
public String definition;
public String trans;
public String img;
public int id;
private String destpath;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private String favoriteState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inner_page);

    final android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int layoutId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("id"));
        String pageName = extras.getString("name");

        assert pageName != null;
        if (pageName.equals("list")) {

            id = MainActivity.list.get(layoutId).getId();
            word = MainActivity.list.get(layoutId).getWord();
            definition = MainActivity.list.get(layoutId).getDefinition();
            trans = MainActivity.list.get(layoutId).getTrans();
            img = MainActivity.list.get(layoutId).getImg();

        } else if (pageName.equals("favorite")) {

            id = MainActivity.favorite.get(layoutId).getId();
            word = MainActivity.favorite.get(layoutId).getWord();
            definition = MainActivity.favorite.get(layoutId).getDefinition();
            trans = MainActivity.favorite.get(layoutId).getTrans();
            img = MainActivity.favorite.get(layoutId).getImg();
        }
    }

    contentDescriptione = findViewById(R.id.content_description);
    moreDescriptione = findViewById(R.id.more_description);
    imgCopy = findViewById(R.id.img_copy);
    imgShare = findViewById(R.id.img_share);
    imgSms = findViewById(R.id.img_sms);
    imgGmail = findViewById(R.id.img_gmail);
    avatar = findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    favorite = findViewById(R.id.favorite);
    collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.getExpandedTitleMarginStart();
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(word);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));

    contentDescriptione.setText(definition);
    moreDescriptione.setText(trans);

    int imgageId = MainActivity.context.getResources().getIdentifier(img, "drawable", MainActivity.context.getPackageName());
    avatar.setImageResource(imgageId);

    SharedPreferences prefes = getSharedPreferences("font_size", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int value = prefes.getInt("fontsize", 16);
    contentDescriptione.setTextSize(value);
    moreDescriptione.setTextSize(value);

    selectDb();

    if(selectFavoriteState()){
        favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_like);
    }else {
        favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_maylike);
    }

    favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (selectFavoriteState()){
                favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_maylike);
                updateUnfavorited();

            }else {
                favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_like);
                updateFavorited();

            }



        }
    });

    imgCopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           final ClipboardManager  clipboardManager =
                   (ClipboardManager)ActivityInnerPage.this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
           final ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(word, trans+definition);

            assert clipboardManager != null;
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Snackbar.make(view,"متن کپی شد ",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    imgShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, definition+trans);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, word);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
        }
    });

    imgGmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {

                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO
                        , Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, word);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, definition);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));

            }catch (Exception e){
                Snackbar.make(view,"برنامه ای برای ارسال ایمیل یافت نشد",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    imgSms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent sendSms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendSms.putExtra("sms_body", definition + trans);
                sendSms.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                startActivity(sendSms);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Snackbar.make(view,"برنامه ای برای ارسال پیام یافت نشد",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


}


private void selectDb(){
    destpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ielts/";
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(destpath + "/md_book.db", null);
}

private boolean selectFavoriteState(){
    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main WHERE id = " + id, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        favoriteState = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fav"));

    }
    return favoriteState.equals("1");
}

private void updateFavorited(){
    database.execSQL( "UPDATE main SET fav = 1 WHERE id = " + id);

}

private void updateUnfavorited(){
    database.execSQL( "UPDATE main SET fav = 0 WHERE id = " + id);


}

}
```

Comment: send the activity code..dont need the adapter code..

Comment: Sure. I updated my post

Comment: where did u update the arraylist ??

Comment: I didn't mention it . where should I do that?

Comment: did you call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter?

Comment: yes I called it in on resume method

Comment: where else I have to call it?

Comment: when you add something to the list you will have to call it.

Comment: I'll update my code in post . please take a look

Comment: Update 2 is my PageFragment

Comment: Where do you actually insert items into a List or ArrayList?

Comment: In Adapter Favorite

Comment: Do you need its codes?

Comment: yes it is needed to solve your problem.

Comment: I added my code in post as update 3 AdapterFav . Please take a look . Tnx in advance

Comment: Share MainActivity code

Comment: I added the code to update 4

Answer (score 0):

In your FloatingActionButton onClick method after you save the new item in your database, insert your new item into your recyclerview datasource list and call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter.

Comment: thanks for your answer . can you help me more with example?

Answer (score 0):

**Choice 1**: in onResume() stub of MainActivity, call  `selectList()` and `selectFavorite()` and then load the PageFragment again so that the new list is loaded properly.

**This is the shortest wayout but this approach is very much unoptimized and is not recommended**.

**Choice 2**: You will have to **insert the new item in database as well as add it to the `List`** and then call `notifyDatasetChanged`

In `MainActivity` within methods `selectList()` and `selectFavorite()` after you perform `list.add(struct)` and `favourite.add(struct)` respectively, you will have to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` for the Adapter.

But the **problem** is your `RecyclerView` is in the `PageFragment` whereas you're populating the list in `MainActivity`.

So move your `selectList()` and `selectFavorite()` to `PageFragment` where you first initialize the `RecylerView` then, set the `Adapter` and then *populate the list* and finally call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your adapters.

Comment: I did as you said but how to get access to selectList() and selectFavorite() in Main activity. It doesnt show anything

Comment: can you also post the code of the complete Activity or Fragment where you add new items to vocabulary?

Comment: Sure . I posted in my question

Comment: which one is it? Update 4?

Comment: Update 2 is page fragment and update 4 is main actactivity

Comment: In which one do you add new item?

Comment: in which activity is your floating button?

Comment: It's in inner activity.I maid 2 methods one makes favorite 1 and the other 0

Comment: So clicking your floating button starts another Activity which is the InnerActivity.

Comment: No my floating button is in inner activity and it only makes Fav column of database 0 or 1

Comment: Sure . If u dont mind it takes about 10 mins to edit my post

Comment: This problem became a nightmare

Comment: I'm sorry. Your Approach is wrong. You will have to make some changes.

Comment: see my edited answer and follow choice one if you don't want to optimize your code and keep the approach.

Comment: So you offer choice one?

Comment: So in that case my codes will update only on second run and after that .what about first run?

Comment: onResume() executes each time the Activity appears, let it be first run or second. So if you populate the List and load the Fragment in onResume() then the RecyclerView will refresh during first run and after adding new item.

Comment: I really appreciate your help . It takes 4 hours to reach home and test code

Comment: Let me know if the code works, and do test it.... and if it has helped you mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Sure tnx a million

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury Why do you advice to reload the whole PageFragment??? This is a very very unprofessional solution...

Comment: I'm actually new in android programming . what do you suggest?

Comment: I tested choice one unfortunately app crashes

Comment: Can you please bring example for choice 2?

Comment: @just......You can see his approach, it is totally wrong. Since he doesn't want to change it I suggested the unprofessional solution. But I've also mentioned that it is not recommended. I have provided another choice also which includes the general method of populating a list and channel it to the RecyclerView.

Comment: @Love......... The answer would be too broad. I suggest you take a look at tutorials of **Populate RecyclerView from MySQL or SQLite DataBase** available abundantly and for the time being avoid using RecyclerView on the Fragment, just keep it in your MainActivity for the sake of Simplicity.

Comment: If you're using **SQLite Database** : https://youtu.be/1ByOLvrJDTA and if you're using **MySQL Database** : https://youtu.be/5iqTZOZCPV4

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury : so there is no way to edit my code to get result . I have limited time and my project is ready if I solve this problems. with these tutorials I have to start everything from beginning

Comment: If there was any way I would have told you. It might be possible but perhaps I'm not being able to figure it out. If you can you may send your project to me but that is not possible I guess.

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury I'd be grateful if u take a look . how can I send my project

Comment: compress it to a ZIP file and send it to koushikchoudhury0@gmail.com

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury tnx alot . I sent the file . please check your gmail